# SonarQube How to see number of code lines of each element in the group on a project using sonarqube?

Tags: java, sonarqube

Well, I'm using sonarQube, and I can see the number of lines of the project, but can I see the number of lines that i have contributed and the number of lines that other elements made?

Answer (score 0):

What you are looking for are features provided by the [SonarQube Developer Cockpit plugin](http://redirect.sonarsource.com/plugins/devcockpit.html).

Note that this is a commercial product developed by SonarSource.